# Placing two roots in ExtJs4 trees

Tags: tree, extjs4

I am trying to build a tree on ExtJs4 with two sub-roots. The concept behind this is to have a tree that replicates “Members Names” divided in two subsets: “Regular Members” and “New Members”
The tree is instantiate correctly. Then when I try to expand "Regular Members" node and then collapse and finally re-expand it I have the following behavior: store load duplicate children. After this “Regular Members” cannot be collapsed. The same thing happens to “New Members” node.
I am straggling two days now to find a solution. Maybe there is a different way to build something like that but I don’t know how.
Any help is appreciated
Tom

the code is:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'TreeModel',
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'http://someUrl/a.cfm',
reader: {
type: 'json',
root: 'DATA'
}
},
root: {
text: 'Regular Members',
id: 'src',
expanded: false
}
});


var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'TreeModel1',
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'http://someUrl/a1.cfm',
reader: {
type: 'json',
root: 'DATA'
}
},
root: {
text: 'New Members',
id: 'src1',
expanded: false
}
});



var TreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
root: {
text: 'Members',
id: 'rtt',
expanded: true
}
});

TreeStore.getRootNode().appendChild(store.getRootNode());
TreeStore.getRootNode().appendChild(store1.getRootNode());


var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
store: TreeStore,
hideHeaders: true,
rootVisible: true,
height: 350,
width: 400,
title: 'Directory Listing',
renderTo: 'tree',
collapsible: true
});


tree.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(sm, selectedRecord) {
var selectedMemberId = selectedRecord[0].data.id;
var rootNode = selectedRecord[0].getId();
if (selectedRecord.length && (selectedRecord[0].getId())!="src" && (selectedRecord[0].getId())!="src1" && (selectedRecord[0].getId())!="rtt"){alert(selectedMemberId);
}
else
{
alert('My root is: ' + rootNode);
}
});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using just one store. It has to have a 'virtual' root node containing as many items as root nodes you want in the first level and set rootVisible: false in the tree. In this way you will have a tree like below:

```
non-visible root
|
+-- first root
|   :
|   
+-- second root
    :
```

But given that you set rootVisible: false, what you will see is

```
+-- first root
|   :
|   
+-- second root
    :
```

UPDATE
This is the json that i have in my project (i have a tree that shows more than just one root)

```
{
    "actions" : [{
        "action" : "Version 1.3.21.0",
        "url" : "/Operations/Version%201.3.21.0"
    }, {
        "action" : "Version 1.3.16.0",
        "url" : "/Operations/Version%201.3.16.0"
    }]
}
```

and this is the model that i use:

```
Ext.define('App.model.PluginAction', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {name: 'text', mapping: 'action'},
        'url',
        'description',
        {
            name: 'leaf', 
            convert: function(val, data) {
                return data.raw && data.raw.children;
            }}
        ],
    hasMany : { model: 'PluginAction', name: 'children'},
    idProperty: 'text'
});
```

And my tree class definition:

```
Ext.define('App.view.layout.PluginActionTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.TreePanel',
    alias: 'widget.pluginActionTree',
    hideHeaders: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    useArrows: true,
    lines: false,
    containerScroll: true,
    autoSize: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    model : 'App.model.PluginAction'
}
```

Good luck!

**Update:**
The problem is that trees can only have just one and only one root node. Once you know it what you have to do is create a root node (which will be hidden) and that root node has to have as many nodes has you need.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    xtype : 'treepanel',
    hideHeaders: true,
    rootVisible: false,  // this is important
    containerScroll: true,
    autoSize: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    root: {
       children : [
          { text: 'root1' },
          { text: 'root2' }]
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});​
```

this works! please, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/FDY6v/

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
I have already tried that but it doesn’t seem to be working.It is loading indefinitely! Can you show me how the json should be formatted in order to work?
Thank you

Comment: The json that I am using:
{"DATA":[
            
            { "text": "Regular Members", "expanded": false, "leaf": false, "children": [
                { "text": "Dinos Michailidis", "leaf": true },
                { "text": "Tom Rigas", "leaf": true}
            ] },
            { "text": "New Members", "expanded": false, "leaf": false, "children": [
                { "text": "George Pap", "leaf": true },
                { "text": "Koni Karamanlis", "leaf": true} ]}
        ]}

Comment: i´ve updated the answer. your json looks right but remember that trees make a new call for load data everytime you expand a node in order to get the rows to create the subtree.

Comment: Thank you for your post but i didn't get you. It is seems not to be working!

Comment: Can you help me on this problem? I have been stuck 5 days now!
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. tak a look at the url that i posted, and please, if it is what you whant accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know that if i place under the root definition any static data like => children : [
     { text: 'root1', children: [{text: 'root1.1', leaf: true},{text: 'root1.2', leaf: true}] },
     { text: 'root2', children: [{text: 'root2.1', leaf: true},{text: 'root2.2', leaf: true}] }] it will work. But i don't want it. I need to load data dynamically. Loading dynamically (even loading from a json file) doesn't work.Any help is appreciated. Thank you again